# Forms of address of Roman Magistrates under Constantinus

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, latin-language

In *The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire*, Gibbon mentions that Roman magistrates under Constantinus the Great had such titles as; your *Sincerity*, your *Gravity*, your *Excellency*, your *Eminence*, your *sublime and wonderful Magnitude*, your *illustrious and magnificent Highness* (Ch. 27 in Volume 2).  I have been trying to find them in the original language with no avail.  I am not even sure if they were originally in Latin or Greek.

A note in *Decline and Fall* suggests Gibbon took those "wonderful" titles from *Notitia Dignitatum*.  I have consulted [that](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/Chronologia/Lspost05/Notitia/not_dor1.html) too, but cannot seem to find anything related.

I hope someone could help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Nice question.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has separate articles on the different ranks, but they are not (as of this writing) systematically categorized. For example: [Illustris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vir_illustris) or [Gloriosissimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vir_gloriosus).

The Illustris article refers to Jones, A.H.M., The Later Roman Empire 284-602, A Social, Economic, and Administrative Survey (Oxford: Blackwell, 1964, repr. Johns Hopkins UP, 1986) which is a famous work and probably has all the information you need.

P.S.
Note that the titles shifted meanings over a centuries and often what had been a very high rank would become an almost entry-level designation a few centuries later.

P.P.S.
If you search your link of the Notitia for 'illustris' you'll find it all over the place.